# How I can solve this python selenium problem?

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
mainurl = 'https://austin.craigslist.org/search/cta?s=0'
driver.get(mainurl)

with open('C:/Users/Saba/Desktop/sample.csv', encoding="utf-8") as f:   
    for  i  in f:
        search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="query"]').send_keys(i)
        submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchform"]/div[1]/button').click()
        driver.get(mainurl)
        driver.close()
```

I want to add the second value from my csv file, how I can append second value from my csv file after it makes one.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: what exactly are you trying to archive? add to you csv file or read from it and add its data to your browser?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to read from csv file and add data into my browser, but it only adds first row and not others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close driver as the final step of iteration so that when your loop goes to the second iteration, your browser is closed.

Try to change this:

```py
with open('C:/Users/Saba/Desktop/sample.csv', encoding="utf-8") as f:   
    for  i  in f:
        search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="query"]').send_keys(i)
        submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchform"]/div[1]/button').click()
        driver.get(mainurl)
        driver.close()
```

to this:

```py
with open('C:/Users/Saba/Desktop/sample.csv', encoding="utf-8") as f:   
    for  i  in f:
        search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="query"]').send_keys(i)
        submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchform"]/div[1]/button').click()
        driver.get(mainurl)

driver.close()
```